# Pivot class attributes

Tags: python, pivot, aggregate

My goal is to achieve a pivot view of monthly expenditures.

I have a list of Expenditure objects which are simple:

```
Date, Subject, Amount
Date, Subject, Amount
Date, Subject, Amount
```

I need to have the result in the following way:

```
        Subject        Subject
Date   SUM(Amount)    SUM(Amount)
Date   SUM(Amount)    SUM(Amount)
```

How can I achieve such a result in Python? I know that in T-SQL, there is the pivot-function I can use for that, but I did not find anything for Python yet.

Comment: What's the structure of your data? do you use database or are the record just tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15/10min.html#min) python library.

```
import pandas as pd
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(data = df, index=['Date'], columns=['Subject'], values='Amount', aggfunc='sum')
```

Where `df`is your dataframe containing data.